# How the VPN finds that the request is a public internet request(google, amazon,etc.,) or a company's intranet request?

Tags: networking, vpn, intranet

I'm using the business VPN in my company. When I am using the internet using vpn, my public ip doesn't change before and after connecting with vpn. But I cannot understand the flow of VPN. The question is if I surfing in internet how the VPN finds that I surfed the company's intranet url's or public url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VPN server is configured to provide the client with a list of IP address ranges which should be tunnelled – the rest are automatically excluded and go through your normal route.

For business VPNs, this list is set by your IT team and includes just the company's IP addresses. (These might be public or private addresses; the VPN doesn't care.)

On Windows you can usually use `route print` to see which addresses are routed through the VPN's virtual network adapter.

(For commercial VPNs, this list is `0.0.0.0/0` and `::/0`, which simply includes everything.)